# How to render a Bitmap property in a Reporting RDLC and render a non corrupted pdf file

Tags: asp.net, reporting, rdlc, httpresponse

I have to render a bitmap in my rdlc (using .Net Reporting) And then render this file in different formats(including pdf).
The DataSet consists of SeriesItemModels objects List that(each item of the list) has one property defined as of the Bitmap type! 
The problem is that I face two problems:
- It seems like the bitmap is not rendered in the rdlc
- The file extension disappears and the downloaded file is corrupted
Here is the Print method (the one that I call within an action to render the pdf file)

```
public class StatisticsStateModels
{       
    public static void Print(List<SeriesItemModels> items, string printFormat)
    {
        ReportViewer rptViewer = new ReportViewer();
        rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

        rptViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Content/States/Statistics.rdlc";
        rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("StatisticsModelsDataSet", StatisticsStateModels.GetStatistics(items)));

        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string filename = now.Year + "" + now.Month + "" + now.Day + "" + now.Hour + "" + now.Minute + "" + now.Second + "" + now.Millisecond;





        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType = string.Empty;
        string encoding = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;

        switch (printFormat.ToLower())
        {
            case "pdf":
                byte[] pdfContent = rptViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

                response.Clear();
                //response.ClearHeaders();
                response.Buffer = true;
                response.ContentType = mimeType;
                response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "." + extension);
                // response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                response.BinaryWrite(pdfContent);
                response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
                response.End();

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and the DataSet method

```
public static List<SeriesItemModels> GetStatistics(List<SeriesItemModels> items)
    {
        return items;
    }
```

Last, you have the SeriesItem model bellow

```
  public class SeriesItemModels
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<object> data { get; set; }
    public Bitmap graph { get; set; }
    public SeriesItemModels() {
        this.name = "";
        this.graph = validBitMap();//be sure: this bitMap is external and valid!
        this.data = new List<object>();
    }
}
```

PS: the validBitMap is generated perfectly and correctly! I tried to save it on the server, It works! But the file remains corrupted despite my efforts.

Can you tell me how to solve theses issues? Why is my file corrupted ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and It works perfectly:
first I changed the Bitmap  graph property into a byte[] array, using the ImageConverter (see bellow)

```
public class SeriesItemModels{
public string name { get; set; }
public List<object> data { get; set; }
private BitMap _graph;
public byte[] graph { get{
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(_bitmap, typeof(byte[]));
}
set{
    //...intentionaly ignored
 } }
    public SeriesItemModels() {
    this.name = "";
    this.graph = validBitMap();//be sure: this bitMap is external and valid!
    this.data = new List<object>();
   }
  }
```

And the files were corrupted because of the post request! I have changed the request into a get request and now files are being downloaded correctly(not corrupted)